# How to handle dynamic variable string value in single line

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my PL/SQL block. When i execute it the result of 'V_QUERY' variable breaks into two lines like:

```
'%[CDATA[/documents/%/4min.png
/%'.
```

How can i get it in one line like below: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NScds.png)

```
'%[CDATA[/documents/%/4min.png/%'
```

.

```
declare
   cursor c1 is
      select rtrim(ltrim(substr(typesettings, 7), '"'), '"') as typesettings
        from trashentry
       where rownum < 2;
   v_query varchar2(32767);
begin
   for r1 in c1
   loop
      v_query := '''%[CDATA[/documents/%/' || r1.typesettings || '/%''';
      dbms_output.put_line(v_query);
   end loop;

end;
```

Comment: Please give an example of the output you want to get.

Comment: `r1.typesettings` probably has a newline at the end. Please show what `select dump(typesettings) from trashentry` shows (if it's too long, show the last few character codes).

Comment: Thank you @ Rene , The Result is as  '%[CDATA[/document/%/4min.png  
/%'                                                                                                          but  I need in single line as  '%[CDATA[/documents/%/4min.png/%'  means in single line

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to trim `chr(10)` from the end of `typesettings`. It may not hurt to trim `chr(13)` as well, on the chance it may be present too.

Assuming there aren't any double-quotes in your input string that you need to keep, you can achieve several things at once: Instead of `rtrim(ltrim(...))` (which should be a `trim(...)` anyway, it does the same thing and is simpler and only calls one function instead of two), you could use `translate`:

```
select translate(substr(typesettings, 7), 'x"' || chr(10) || chr(13), 'x') as typesettings
.......
```

Notice the `x` in the last two parameters; it doesn't really do anything, it just works around a limitation of the `translate` function (which in turn is due to Oracle's treatment of empty strings as `NULL`). In this example, `translate` will replace every `x` in the input string with `x`, and every occurrence of `"`, `chr(10)` and `chr(13)` will be simply deleted.